# Use Directive two times in one controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use same directives multiple times in one controller in AngularJS. I want to create a list widget that can be used multiple times. I can display two widgets at the same time under the same controller. But, I am unable to bind teamA and teamB data to ng-repeat in my directive. In addition to that, the code fails during addTeamMember() because datasource is undefined. I was hoping that datasource will be updated with teamA and teamB respectively.

Here is the HTML code.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl"><div class="container">
   <my-directive datasource="model.teamA"></my-directive>
   <my-directive datasource="model.teamB"></my-directive>
</div></div>
```

Controller.js:

```
angular.module('app',[])
   .controller('myCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope){
       $scope.teamA = {};
       $scope.teamB = {};
} ] );
```

Directive.js:

```
angular.module('app', [] )
   .directive('myDirective', function(){
       return{
           restrict: 'AE',
           templateUrl: 'directive_html.html',
        scope: {
            datasource: "=TeamMembers"
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.addTeamMember = function(){
                 scope.datasource.push({});
            };
            scope.removeTeamMember = function(item){
                 scope.datasource.splice(item, 1);
            };
        }
    };
}) ;
```

directive_html.html:

```
<div><div class="container">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="member in TeamMembers">
        <textarea ng-model="member.text" rows="2"></textarea> 
        <a href="" ng-click="removeTeamMember($index)">Remove</a>
    <div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addTeamMember()">Add</button>
</div></div>
```

Could anyone please help me out here? I want to create custom Widgets that can be used multiple places either in same controllers or in different controllers.

Thanks

Comment: Here, `datasource` is the name of your variable in directive `scope`, not the attribute name.
Use `datasource: "=datasource"` so you can use `datasource` attribute in your HTML.
`datasource: "="` works too (shortcut for using same name as attribute)

Comment: I have corrected the "=datasource" in my HTML. But, If I have initialize teamA and teamB data in controller, then I don't see any data in the directive. I might be missing something for binding data between controller and directive. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

As @Neozaru pointed out in comments.  You are expecting the directive attribute to be called `team-members` here:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl"><div class="container">
   <my-directive team-members="model.teamA"></my-directive>
   <my-directive team-members="model.teamB"></my-directive>
</div></div>
```

You do this when you define the isolated scope as:

```
scope: {
    datasource: "=TeamMembers"
}
```

The above line is saying, "`team-members` is what the *outside* attribute will be named, but internally I'll refer to the referenced object as `scope.datasource`".